# Definition of a symbol in a .so file on Solaris

Tags: solaris

Could somebody tell me how to find the definition of a symbol in a shared object file on Solaris.

Thanks
Raj

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the Solaris machines I have access to nm is available and can be used for this. For instance:

```
nm /usr/lib/libc.so
```

Shows all of the symbols in libc.so and then checking if a symbol is defined in this library is simply a matter of reading through the output.

Probably you want to pass the -g and -D options too for most cases. If you're looking to search a bunch of libraries you could try using:

```
find /usr/lib -name '*.so' -exec nm -gD {} \; |grep "symbol_name"
```

Or similar